# Null object refrences in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to created a chat app project with android studio and when I want to run my project my app crashed please help me?

**My code is below:**

```
private void readUser()
{
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (search.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                mUsers.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    assert user != null;
                    assert firebaseUser != null;

                    if (!user.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }
                }
                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my **error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.mahdi.chatapp.Fragments.UsersFragment$3.onDataChange(UsersFragment.java:132)
```

and error from this **line:**

```
if (!user.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
```

Comment: `user` or `user.getId()` or `firebaseUser` or `firebaseUser.getUid()` is `null`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see what's throwing the nullpointer? "user" or "firebaseUser" might just be null

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773384/android-firebase-cant-get-userid-using-getuid-error-on-null-object-refere